# Measure theory question I encountered

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $X$ is compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $µ$ is a finite measure on $(X, \mathcal{B}_X)$.

Let $a < b ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $f : X × [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ be  $\mathcal{B}_X × \mathcal{B}_{[a,b]}$ -measurable and bounded.

Assume also that $\dfrac{∂f}{
∂t} (x, t)$ is jointly continuous. Prove that $F(t) = \int_Xf(x,t)d\mu(x)$ is continuously differentiable on $[a, b]$ (usual convention at the endpoints) and $$F'(t)=\dfrac{∂f}{
∂t} (x, t)d\mu(x)$$ for all $t ∈ [a, b]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(t+h) - F(t) -h \int_X \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t,x) d\mu(x)
 = \int_X \left(f(x,t+h) - f(x,t) - h\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t,x) \right)d\mu(x)
$$
Now using the Taylor theorem:
$$
= \int_X 
\int_t^{t+h}\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (u,x) du  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t,x)\right)du
d\mu(x)
\\=\int_X 
\int_a^b 1_{t\le u\le t+h}\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (u,x) du  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (t,x)\right)du
d\mu(x)
$$

using the continuity of
$$
(u,t)\to 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (u,x) $$
and the fact that $X\times [a,b]$ is compact, you can use the dominated convergence theorem (with domination by a constant) to get that this quantity goes to $0$.

Comment: Could you kindly explain what you mean by $$
(u,t)\to 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (u,x) $$

Comment: this is just the function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ written with $u$ instead of $t$.